# Reciprocal of the reciprocal of zero

Tags: inverse

By straightforward evaluation,
$$(0^{-1})^{-1}=(NaN)^{-1}=NaN$$
where $\frac{1}{0}$ is taken to equal $NaN$ (not a number), or undefined or indeterminate.
However, the laws of exponents state that
$$(x^m)^n=x^{mn}$$
so the original equation should theoretically be evaluated as:
$$(0^{-1})^{-1}=0^{(-1)(-1)}=0^1=0$$
Is one more correct than the other, or is this just one of the discrepancies when working with $\frac{1}{0}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(x^{m})^n=x^{mn}$ is not true for any $x$ and any $m,n$. Either $m,n\in\Bbb N,m,n\geq 1$ or $x$ has to be positive.

This is a classical mistake. Abusing this rule you can also prove that
$$-1 = (-1)^{1}=(-1)^{2/2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1}=1$$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I've seen the -1 = 1 concept before, but now I understand the reasoning against it. Thanks for your help.